# Javascript not working when loaded async

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I had the following code on my page:

```
<script src="https://chatserver.comm100.com/js/LiveChat.js?siteId=&amp;planId=2594&amp;partnerId=-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This script takes forever to load and so I wanted to load it async, so it does it's own thing while the rest of the page is downloaded / rendred. So I put in this code:

```
(function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = 'https://chatserver.comm100.com/js/LiveChat.js?siteId=&amp;planId=2594&amp;partnerId=-1';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);
  })();
```

But when I use the latter, the code does not run. It is a little hard to debug, since the file is minified.

Is there anything I am missing about the async loading? Any other steps I need to take?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to use the HTML5 async attribute? Why not just put that attribute in your `<script>` tag?

Comment: The async attribute is just to future proof the code. It was recommended by Google. I'll remove it, to help you get over it.

Comment: Do you have any other script tags on your markup? If you don't, `x` will be undefined.

Comment: x can't be undefined, because you have atleast one script containing the snippet above. the js file uses document.write to load additional scripts, so I guess this breaks it.

Comment: @jasssonpet Obviously! How could I miss that!

Comment: @bfavaretto - Even if that was not the case, the page contains script tags aplenty :)

Comment: @jasssonpet I was thinking that too, but I don't get why. Loading the script in this way creates a tag like any other regular script tag. The only thing I can think of is that maybe the script "misses" the document.ready event. Is that a known thing?

Comment: Did you try the other options presented [here](http://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/)? It says that pattern will block `window.onload` -- meaning it won't be triggered until the script has finished loading, so it's not truly async. But it says nothing about `document.ready` (which may be dispatched even before the script has finished loading).

Answer (score 0):

async is a new HTML5 attribute for the script tag.  You'll want to [check browser support](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_script_async.asp).  When supported, you should not have to have your custom script at all; just write:

```
<script ... async="async"></script>
```

Comment: You are right, but there is no support yet, so this doesn't really help me at all. Thanks for taking the time to answer though.